# Bootstrap hamburger menu icon-bars wont change color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to change the hamburger menu icon-bars to color white. But its not changing. How Do i change the icon-bars colors? I think its stuck in default color.

html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-
        toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false" 
        aria-controls="navbar">

        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">WASHINGTOWN</a>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

css

```
navbar-default .navbar-toggle,
.navbar-default, span.icon-bar {
color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff !important;;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-
        toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false" 
        aria-controls="navbar">

        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">WASHINGTOWN</a>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you @dude_berkeley  :)

Answer (score 0):

Changed some menu color, look at

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: red;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: red;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: green;
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/1200x400?text=IMAGE" alt="Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Sell $</h3>
          <p>Money Money.</p>
        </div>      
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/1200x400?text=Another Image Maybe" alt="Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>More Sell $</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>      
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
  


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar
```

Target that selector, in the CSS you provided, commas divide selectors, and thus your selector is not specific enough to override the default colour. Additionally. ensure your CSS file's  tag is below the one for Bootstrap.